# URL as field in Java Object

Tags: java, url, object, constructor, try-catch

I have an object which contains a field of type `String`, with a value similar to "http://stackoverflow.com"

I have a method which must take a `URL`. So I am wrapping that in a method which takes the `String`, and then constructs a `URL` from the `String` (which apparently needs to be wrapped in a try catch...)

It seems like there should be a simpler way. Is it possible to just store my value in the object as a `URL`, rather than a `String`? I tried this `public URL url = "http://stackoverflow.com";`

Is it possible to do something along those lines? Is there a better way than what I was doing originally?

Thanks

original:

```
public String urlString = "http://stackoverflow.com";


public boolean myMethod(String urlString) {
 try {
        URL newURL = new URL(urlString);
        useUrl(newURL);
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Doesnt work, but seems better:

```
public URL url = "http://stackoverflow.com";


public boolean myMethod(URL url) {
        useUrl(url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception handling is necessary, because Java has no way of knowing that your String can be converted into a URL until it attempts to do so.

Probably what you really want to do is:

```
static URL URLofString(String s){
 URL r=null;
 try { 
   r= new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");  
  } catch (MalformedURLException e) { } 
  return r;
 }
```

and then

```
final static URL myURL=URLofString("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

in Java 8, you will be able to use a lambda, although it's scarcely better:

```
final static URL myURL = ()->{
  URL r=null; 
  try {  r= new URL("http://stackoverflow.com");  }
  catch (MalformedURLException e) { } return r;};
```

Answer (score 3):

Java doesn't support implicit conversions. If you want to turn one type into another you have to do it explicitly like

```
final URL url = new URL("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

however this throws a checked exception so you need a helper method like

```
private static final URL url = getUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/");

private static URL getUrl(String spec)  {
    try {
        return new URL(spec);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

or use a constructor

```
private final URL url;

public MyClass(String spec) throws MalformedURLException {
    url = new URL(spec);
}
```

Comment: its still telling me it cant handle exception thrown by super constructor.

Comment: so you have to add it to the throws clause of your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood what you wanna do, but do this helps you?

```
class SomeClass {
  private final String urlString = "http://stackoverflow.com";
  public URL url;

  public SomeClass() {
     try {
        this.url = new URL(this.urlString); // suppose the URL is correct
     } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm already doing. But I was just thinking, I only use the url in this case. I'll never need to use it as a String, so why store it as a String and then require the extra lines to wrap it in try/catch for the conversion. If could just store it as URL - problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You could shorten it a bit, but you need to create a new URL object.

```
public boolean myMethod(String urlString) {
 try {

        useUrl(new URL(urlString));
 } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at URIBuilder within Spring and Apache, for a little bit of extra magic.

```
URIBuilder uriBuilder = URIBuilder.fromUri( "http://stackoverflow.com/" );
URI uri = uriBuilder.build();
```

Comment: How is that any better than just using `URI uri = new URI("http://stackoverflow.com/");` ?

Comment: Mostly for uriBuilder.queryParams() method.  It takes in a MultiValueMap and makes added query parameters a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. URL's cannot be malformed by definition. Thus, if the problem is to avoid the try/catch, your classes should use `String` instead of `URL`, and converted to `URL` internally when it's required.

You can create a new object that can be safely transformed to URL:

```
private class UnsafeURL {
    private String url;

    public UnsafeURL(String url){
        this.url = url;
    }

    public URL toURL() throws MalformedURLException {
        return new URL(url);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Foo {  

  private URL test;
    {
        try {
            test = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
   public Foo() {

   }
}
```

or

```
public class Foo {  

  private URL test;

   public Foo() {
        try {
            test = new URL("http://www.google.com");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
   }
}
```

Either will work. Best approach would be to do it in the constructor.